# reading node from xml file in XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to grab the `TopicName` how should i go after it and try different combination but somehow i am unable to get `TopicName` below is my source codee...

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();//xml doc used for xml parsing

    xdoc.Load(
        "http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"
        );//loading XML in xml doc

    XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("content");//reading node so that we can traverse thorugh the XML

    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodelst)//traversing XML 
    {
        //litFeed.Text += "read";
    }
```

sample xml file

```
<content type="application/xml">
 <CatalogItems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="sitename.xsd">
        <CatalogSource Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC Corporation" />
        <CatalogItem Id="3212" CatalogUrl="urlname">
          <ContentItem xmlns:content="sitename.xsd" TargetUrl="url">
            <content:SelectionSpec ClassList="" ElementList="" />
            <content:Language Value="eng" Scheme="ISO 639-2" />
            <content:Source Acronym="ABC" OrganizationName="ABC Corporation" />
            <content:Topics Scheme="ABC">
              <content:Topic TopicName="Marketing" />
              <content:Topic TopiccName="Coverage" />
            </content:Topics>
          </ContentItem>
        </CatalogItem>
      </CatalogItems>
    </content>
```

Comment: The Url in your newly updated sample code produces totally different Xml than your sample xml, there is not `CatalogItem` nor content namespace in that xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Topic` nodes in your XML are using the `content` namespace - you need to declare and use the XML namespace in your code, then you can use `SelectNodes()` to grab the nodes of interest - this worked for me:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("content", "sitename.xsd");

var topicNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//content:Topic", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
{
    string topic = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
}
```

Just as a comparison see how easy this would be with Linq to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "sitename.xsd";
string topic = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Topic")
                   .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("TopicName"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

To get all topics you can replace the last statement with:

```
var topics = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Topic")
                 .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("TopicName"))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: if i use #1 solution i get this error `Namespace prefix content is not defined`

Comment: @Abu: I tested this and code works fine for me - did you include the namespace manager?

Comment: Also this assumes you have already loaded your xml into `xdoc`

Comment: if i use the second option which is `linq to xml` i will get just one topicname based on your code but where as i will have mulitple topicname as you loop through all my xml... just wondering how would you do that

Comment: @Abu: Your xml currently has only one topic name - I guess `TopiccName` in the second node is a typo then? - Answer updated

Comment: sorry you are correct its a typo so i have total of two `TopicName` i will try your second solution but what `ns` i know its refering to namespace but what namespace it expecting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3544/discussion-between-brokenglass-and-abu-hamzah)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a specific element, then I'd use XPath:

This is a guide to use XPath in C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/usingXPathNavigator.aspx

And this is the query that will get you a collection of your Topics:

```
//content/CatalogItems/CatalogItem/ContentItem/content:Topics/content:Topic
```

You could tweak this query depending on what it is you're trying to accomplish, grabbing just a specific TopicName value:

```
//content/CatalogItems/CatalogItem/ContentItem/content:Topics/content:Topic/@TopicName
```

XPath is pretty easy to learn.  I've done stuff like this pretty quickly with no prior knowledge.

You can paste you XML and xpath query here to test your queries:

http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/

Comment: i tried the first solution but did not work... it retuns 0 count.

Comment: If you copy your XML and that query in the xpath tool you see it should be returning an item so not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: will you show me the steps i tried pasting the xml in the `www.bit-101.com/xpath` tool and after that? on the right side it says `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The following quick and dirty LINQ to XML code obtains your TopicNames and prints them on the console.

```
XDocument lDoc = XDocument.Load(lXmlDocUri);

foreach (var lElement in lDoc.Element("content").Element(XName.Get("CatalogItems", "sitename.xsd")).Elements(XName.Get("CatalogItem", "sitename.xsd")))
{
     foreach (var lContentTopic in lElement.Element(XName.Get("ContentItem", "sitename.xsd")).Element(XName.Get("Topics", "sitename.xsd")).Elements(XName.Get("Topic", "sitename.xsd")))
     {
           string lTitle = lContentTopic.Attribute("TopicName").Value;
           Console.WriteLine(lTitle);
     }
}
```

It'd have been a lot shorter if it wasn't for all the namespaces :) (Instead of "XName.Get" you would just use the name of the element).

Comment: throwing an error first `foreach` the errors is `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: My code works for your sample, for generic XMLs in which there might not be a content node, for example, you just need to ask if lDoc.Element("content") != null.